# Scheduled task in Spring Boot using existing Controller

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a scheduled task in Spring Boot. I already have a definition for it, which looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
    private static long count = 0;

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000)
    public void createTasks() {

        count++;

        Task t = new Task();
        t.setTitle("Scheduled Task " + count);
        //TaskController tc = new TaskController();
        //tc.create(t);
        taskRepository.saveAndFlush(t);

        log.info("A new scheduled task has been created!");
    }
}
```

This works all fine, but I'm using the interface for my repository directly. Instead of using the repository directly, I want to use the existing controller class that I have. I have a controller class which looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "tasks", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Task create(@RequestBody Task task) {
        return taskRepository.saveAndFlush(task);
    }
}
```

So, how can I actually call this create method for task creation in the `ScheduledTasks` class? If I try to do something like `new TaskController()` as I have commented out, I'm getting a null reference error. Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `new TaskController()`, the instance that you created is not going to be managed by Spring, therefore, the IoC (autowiring the dependencies) will not happen.

I believe that you simply want to use the Spring managed instance of the controller, in which case, simply autowire it in your ScheduledTask component. (like below (untested))

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
    private static long count = 0;

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TaskController tc;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 15000)
    public void createTasks() {

        count++;

        Task t = new Task();
        t.setTitle("Scheduled Task " + count);
        tc.create(t);
        taskRepository.saveAndFlush(t);

        log.info("A new scheduled task has been created!");
    }
}
```

Comment: While that technically works, it seems very wrong to put that kind of functionality in your `Controller` class. The only concern of a Controller has to be with the UI.

Comment: Better yet extract the common functionality into a service class and use the service in both controller and task! ✅

Comment: I agree that that is not a good design, there should be a separation of concerns, and you would probably want to abstract that login in a Service class (using the service stereotype) and have both, the ScheduledTask and the Controller, use the service (autowired).

Comment: You inject the `TaskController`and call it's `create(Task)`method, but forgot to remove the use of the `TaskRepository` which was the original purpose of this post.